# Как правильно записать значение value в option

Tags: php, html, mysql

При оформлении новой записи в адресную книгу используется справочник должностей, соответственно value записывается в базу данных как id_post и хранится в виде цифры. Когда выводим запись на редактирование я заполнял value непосредственно "должностью" а не цифрой должности, соответственно при попытке сохранить выдается ошибка. Вопрос как правильно отображать value у option при редактировании?

```html
 <label for="post">Выберите должность</label>
     <select name="post" id="post">
        <option><?php echo $edit == 1 ? $row->post : 'Укажите должность' ?></option>
        <?php echo $html3 ?> // выводится список из БД 
     </select>
```

Comment: `<option value="ваш id_post">Собственно post</option>`

Comment: Спасибо помогло!